# MediaWiki styling for iPhone

Tags: iphone, mediawiki, wikipedia

When you visit en.wikipedia.org with an iPhone you are forwarded to en.m.wikipedia.org which is formatted beautifully for the device. I have MediaWiki on my own server and I'd love to have this formatting available when I visit my site with my iPhone. Is there an easy way to enable this? I've gotten as far as www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgHandheldForIPhone and http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileSkin but nothing is jumping out at me.

Answer (score 7):

I operate Wikiaudio and this is what I did:

Install and use [this extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMobileDetect), to detect [this skin (WP touch)](http://www.memorydeleted.com/?p=210).

Answer (score 4):

m.wikipedia.org is based on the wikimedia-mobile server, whose source code is available here:

http://github.com/hcatlin/wikimedia-mobile

It's a proxy of sorts that gets pages from Wikipedia, shuffles the contents and then serves them out formatted for mobiles, with caching to speed up things.  It's written in Ruby and seems to be fairly customized for Wikipedia and the Monobook skin.

Comment: This was the case at that point, however now this gateway is not used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia uses [MobileFrontend](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMobileFrontend).

Answer (score 0):

You posted a link with complete instructions on how to deploy this into your installation of MediaWiki...

-t

Comment: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileSkin does NOT contain *complete* instructions. It talks about setting up the extension to determine if the visitor has an iPhone but it doesn't cover which style sheets to use or how to use the extension to serve those style sheets to iPhone users. I've got the extension on my server and I followed every direction on the page but all it does is hide some of the styles. I get the same fonts and colors but not the regular top-bar-plus-side-column layout, and it's all small. I'm still lacking the iPhone-specific styling found at en.m.wikipedia.org.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's a skin that's on general release yet and was developed specifically for Wikipedia.